# Send mails from gmail account through SMTP using Oauth in Java

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, smtp, gmail

I am able to send mails using SMTP. But I need to implement Oauth to avoid using password while sending mails. This can be done using accesstoken.

After lot of surfing, i got below snippet.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", userEmail);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");


    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
    props.put("mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken", oauthToken);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    session.setDebug(debug);


    final URLName unusedUrlName = null;
    SMTPTransport transport = new SMTPTransport(session, unusedUrlName);
    // If the password is non-null, SMTP tries to do AUTH LOGIN.
    final String emptyPassword = "";
    transport.connect(host, port, userEmail, emptyPassword);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
```

I am struggling to connect using `SMTPTransport.connect` with **empty password.**

Can anyone help me whether I can `SEND_MAILS + SMTP + OAUTH + GMAIL_ACCESS_TOKEN?`

I appreciate working code suggestions. Thanks